# Can't get onChange function to work on React with Grid Containers

Tags: javascript, reactjs, grid, onchange

Got the pictured error while trying to set up onChange event handler for the FormRow function. Ultimately need to store the user data from Que Reset Time, Service Level threshold and Short Abandoned Threshold. The Queuecontainer is the main class that uses the editor to create the container forms.

[image]

QuesContainer.js

```
import React from 'react';
import Editor from './Editor';
import LoginForm from '../LoginForm';
import axios from 'axios';

export default class QueuesContainer extends React.Component {
       constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        workspaceSID: '',
        apiKey: '',
        apiSecret: '',
        queues: [],
        name: '',
    }
    this.listQueues = this.listQueues.bind(this);
    this.setCredentials = this.setCredentials.bind(this);
    this.getCredentials = this.getCredentials.bind(this);
    this.setQueues = this.setQueues.bind(this);
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
}

/*
handleChange(target) {
    this.setState({ [target.id]: target.value });
}
*/


//Added by JR for Save Function
handleChange(event){
    console.log("From handle change", event);
    this.setState({ name: event.target.value })
}

/*
handleSubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    this.props.login(this.state.workspaceSID, this.state.apiKey, this.state.apiSecret);
}
*/

handleSubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var text = this.state.text;
    console.log("form testing value output:");
}


setCredentials(workspaceSID, apiKey, apiSecret) {
    this.setState({ workspaceSID: workspaceSID });
    this.setState({ apiKey: apiKey });
    this.setState({ apiSecret: apiSecret });
}

getCredentials() {
    return this.state;
}

setQueues(queues) {
    this.setState({ queues: queues });
}




getConfig(apiKey, apiSecret) {
    return axios.get(`https://flex-api.twilio.com/v1/Configuration`, {
        auth: {
            username: apiKey,
            password: apiSecret
        },
    });


    
}


//Added by JR used to post configuration 
postConfig(apiKey, apiSecret, params) {
    return axios.post(`https://flex-api.twilio.com/v1/Configuration`, {
        auth: {
            username: apiKey,
            password: apiSecret
        },
     
    });
}


listQueues(workspaceSID, apiKey, apiSecret) {
    this.setCredentials(workspaceSID, apiKey, apiSecret);
    const queuesPromise = axios.get(`https://taskrouter.twilio.com/v1/Workspaces/${workspaceSID}/TaskQueues?PageSize=1000&Page=0`, {
        auth: {
            username: apiKey,
            password: apiSecret
        },
    });
    const channelsPromise = axios.get(`https://taskrouter.twilio.com/v1/Workspaces/${workspaceSID}/TaskChannels?PageSize=1000&Page=0`, {
        auth: {
            username: apiKey,
            password: apiSecret
        },
    });


    const configPromise = this.getConfig(apiKey, apiSecret);
    

    Promise.all([queuesPromise, channelsPromise, configPromise])
        .then((values) => {
            console.log(values);
            const twilioQueues = values[0].data.task_queues;
            const twilioChannels = values[1].data.channels;
            // const config = values[2].data.queue_stats_configuration;

            const voice = twilioChannels.find(channel => {
                console.log(channel)
                return channel.unique_name === 'voice'
            });

            const chat = twilioChannels.find(channel => {
                console.log(channel)
                return channel.unique_name === 'chat'
            });

            const email = twilioChannels.find(channel => {
                console.log(channel)
                return channel.unique_name === 'email'
            });

            const channels = [voice, chat, email];
            const queues = twilioQueues.map(q => {
                const queue = {
                    queue_sid: q.sid,
                    friendly_name: q.friendly_name,
                    channels
                }
                return queue;
            });

            this.setQueues(queues);
        });
}
   //onChange={this.handleInputChange.bind(this)}

render() {
    const { name } = this.state
    return (
        <div>
            <p> Test Value is : {name}  </p>
            <LoginForm login={this.listQueues} buttonText='Load Queues' />
            
            <Editor onSubmit={this.handleSubmit} onChange={this.handleChange} data={this.state.queues} credentials={this.getCredentials} setData={this.setQueues} />
        </div>
    );
}
}
```

Editor.js

```
import React from 'react';
import MaterialTable from 'material-table'
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';
import TextField from '@material-ui/core/TextField';
import Grid from '@material-ui/core/Grid';
import axios from 'axios';
import { waitForDomChange } from '@testing-library/react';

export default class Editor extends React.Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        open: false,
        queue: {},
        columns: [
            { title: 'Queue Name', field: 'friendly_name', editable: 'never' },
            { title: 'Channel', field: 'channel_friendly_name', editable: 'never' },
            { title: 'Reset Timezone', field: 'channel_reset_timezone' },
            { title: 'Reset Time', field: 'channel_reset_time' },
            { title: 'Service Level Threshold', field: 'channel_service_level_threshold', type: 'numeric' },
            { title: 'Short Abandoned Threshold', field: 'channel_service_level_threshold', type: 'numeric' },
        ]
    }
    this.handleClose = this.handleClose.bind(this);
   // this.handleSave = this.handleSave.bind(this);

}




handleClose(xxx) {
    console.log('this happening');
    console.log(xxx);
    this.setState({ open: true });
}

/*
handleSave(event) {
    console.log('Saving user input data');
    console.log(event);

    this.setState({ value: event.target.value});
}
*/




render() {
    console.log('hey ho');
    console.group(this.props.data);
    const queues = this.props.data.map(q => {
        const channel = q.channels.find(c => c.unique_name === 'voice');
        q.channel_friendly_name = channel.friendly_name;
        q.channel_reset_time = channel.reset_time;
        q.channel_reset_timezone = channel.reset_timezone;
        q.channel_service_level_threshold = channel.service_level_threshold;
        q.channel_service_level_threshold = channel.service_level_threshold;

        return q;


    })
    return (
        <div>
            <MaterialTable
                title='Queue SLA'
                columns={this.state.columns}
                data={queues}
                options={{
                    pageSize: 25,
                    pageSizeOptions: [25, 100, 500, 1000]
                }}
                detailPanel={rowData => {

                    //Modified by JR for Save Function
                    return FormContainer(rowData, this.props.credentials().apiKey, 
this.props.credentials().apiSecret, this.handleChange);
                  
                }}
                
            />
        </div>
    );
}
}



function FormRow(data, handleChange) {
const queue = data.data;
const channels = queue.channels;



return (
    channels.map((channel, index) => (
        <Grid container item sm={12} spacing={3}>
            <Grid item sm={2}>
                <TextField
                    autoFocus
                    margin="dense"
                    id="channel_name"
                    label="Channel"
                    type="text"
                    value={channel.friendly_name}
                    fullWidth
                    disabled
                />
            </Grid>
            <Grid item sm={2}>
                <TextField
                    autoFocus
                    margin="dense"
                    id="reset_timezone"
                    label="Reset Timezone"
                    type="text"
                    value="GMT"
                    fullWidth
                    disabled
                />
            </Grid>

          
         

            <Grid item sm={2}>
                <TextField
                    autoFocus
                    margin="dense"
                    id="service_level_threshold"
                    label="Service Level Threshold"
                    value={channel.service_level_threshold}
                    onChange={handleChange}
                    type="text"
                    fullWidth
                />
            </Grid>
            <Grid item sm={2}>
                <TextField
                    autoFocus
                    margin="dense"
                    id="short_abandoned_threshold"
                    label="Short Abandoned Threshold"
                    value={channel.short_abandoned_threshold}
                    onChange={handleChange}
                    type="text"
                    fullWidth
                />
            </Grid>
        </Grid>
    ))
);
}


 //Modified by JR for Save Function
    function FormContainer(data, apiKey, apiSecret, props, handleChange) {
    console.log('what');
   console.log(data);
    console.log('JSON what');
    console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
    const queue = data;




  // const queue = data.data;
   const channels = queue.channels;


const cancel = () => {
    console.log('cancel');
}



const save = () => {

    //Modified by JR for Save Function
    console.log('save');
    console.log(data);

    console.log(JSON.stringify(data));

    console.log('SaveButtonClicked');
    waitForDomChange();

    console.log(data);

    console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
    savebuttonclicked(queue, apiKey, apiSecret);

    
    console.log('Props Information');
    console.log(props);
 



    console.log('Save Sucessful');

}
return (
    <div>
        <Grid container>
            <Grid item sm={1}></Grid>
            <Grid container item sm={11} spacing={3}>
                <FormRow data={queue}
                    formOnChange={handleChange}/>
                
            </Grid>
            <Grid
                container
                direction="row"
                justify="flex-end"
                alignItems="center"
            >
                <Grid item sm={1}></Grid>
                <Grid item sm={11} spacing={3} justify="flex-end"
                    alignItems="center">


                   
                    <Grid item sm={2}>
                        <TextField 
                            autoFocus
                            margin="dense"
                            id="reset_time"
                            label="Queue Reset Time"
                            type="text"
                            value={channels.reset_time}
                            onChange={handleChange}
                            fullWidth
                            
                        />
                    </Grid>

                    <Button variant="outlined" onClick={cancel} color="secondary">Cancel</Button>
                    <Button variant="outlined" onClick={save} color="primary">Save</Button>


                </Grid>
            </Grid>
        </Grid>
    </div>
);
}

//Add by JR for Save Function
function savebuttonclicked(data, apiKey, apiSecret) {

const workspace = workspaces[0];

console.log('Test');

alert(JSON.stringify(data));
console.log(JSON.stringify(data));


var params = [];

for (const [index, value] of data.channels.entries()) {
    params.push({
        'url': data.channels[index].url,
        'unique_name': data.channels[index].unique_name,
        'account_sid': data.channels[index].account_sid,
        'channel_reset_time': data.channels[index].channel_reset_time,
        'channel_reset_timezone': data.channels[index].channel_reset_timezone,
        'channel_service_level_threshold': data.channels[index].channel_service_level_threshold
    })
}

alert(JSON.stringify(params));
console.log('Parms for API post:');
console.log(JSON.stringify(params));

/* 
 * Loop for API call for each URL in created JSON
 * 
for (const [index, value] of params.entries())
 {
    axios.post(params[index].url, params[index], {
        auth: {
            username: apiKey,
            password: apiSecret,
        }
    })
}
*/

axios.get(workspace.apiURL, {
    auth: {
        username: apiKey,
        password: apiSecret,
    },
})

    .then(function (response) {
        alert('Save Sucessful.')
        alert(JSON.stringify(response))

        console.log('success');
        console.log(response.headers);
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
        alert('Error Occured.')
        alert(error)

        console.log('Error');
        console.log(error);
    });
 }
```

With applied fix this is new error:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'channels' of undefined FormRow
> C:/Users/drago/Source/Repos/twilio-flex-editor/src/queues/Editor.js:99
> 96 | 97 | function FormRow({ data, handleChange }) { 98 | const queue
> = data.data; > 99 | const channels = queue.channels; 100 | 101 | 102 | View compiled ▶ 18 stack frames were collapsed.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Issue

You have defined `FormRow` to consume a `handleChange` callback and also incorrectly defined the props. They should be destructured from a single props object.

```
function FormRow(data, handleChange) {...
```

but have passed an `formOnChange` prop callback

```
<FormRow data={queue} formOnChange={handleChange} />
```

You also pass `this.handleChange` to `Editor` but never consume it

```
<Editor
  onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}
  onChange={this.handleChange}
  data={this.state.queues}
  credentials={this.getCredentials}
  setData={this.setQueues}
/>
```

and (possibly coincidentally) pass an undefined `this.handleChange` function on to `FormContainer` which is passed to `FormRow` component.

## Solution

Fix the `FormRow` component definition

```
function FormRow({ data, handleChange }) {...
```

Pass `handleChange` on to `FormRow` as `handleChange`.

```
<FormRow data={queue} handleChange={handleChange} />
```

Either define `this.handleChange` in `Editor` to be passed, or pass `this.props.onChange` on.

```
return FormContainer(
  rowData,
  this.props.credentials().apiKey,
  this.props.credentials().apiSecret,
  this.props.onChange,
);
```

Comment: Thank you, i made the changes advised above but now received the following error: 

TypeError: Cannot read property 'channels' of undefined
FormRow
C:/Users/drago/Source/Repos/twilio-flex-editor/src/queues/Editor.js:99
   96 | 
   97 | function FormRow({ data, handleChange }) {
   98 |     const queue = data.data;
>  99 |     const channels = queue.channels;
  100 | 
  101 |    
  102 | 
View compiled
▶ 18 stack frames were collapsed.

Comment: @Hun73r3006 In your previous code, `data` was being treated as your "props" object and `handleChange` was undefined, this is why `data.data` worked. It was synonymous to `props.data`. With my above fix, `data` has already been destructured *from* `props`, so you can simply destructure `queue` from `data`, `const { queue } = data;`, now `data.queue.channels` or `queue.channels` will work.

Comment: Great, that worked I was still accessing it via Data.data. Thank you. In terms of storing the data back back to data and passing the new inputs to SaveButtonClicked function, create the in queue container and pass those? I tested something similar and the data is not being updated.

Comment: @Hun73r3006 This follow-on question may be a bit off-topic for *this* SO post, you should ask a new question with details. Looks like your `save` function just calls `savebuttonclicked` and passes whatever the current `data`/`queue` prop/argument value is. TBH I don't quite follow what you are asking about.

Answer (score 0):

This is a picture to the error i received:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z5Xhv.jpg)